# Fitting a known function to data in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, data-fitting

I'm trying to get how well a known function fits to a set of data. I'm not interested in the data's line of best fit or anything, I just want to know how close it is to my model. I've tried using curve_fit and linregress but neither really give me what I'm after. My data follows a logarithmic curve, which I've been plotting up on loglog scales to get a gradient of about -4, which is close to my model (-3.9), but I'd like to know exactly how close. Linregress so far is the closest match for what I'm after, as it gives the correlation coefficient, how well the data follows the line of best fit, but it's still not exactly what I want.

```
def line(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

x = np.log(range(len(coll_ave)))
x = x[1:] # I've done this to avoid the whole ln(0)=infinity thing
y = np.log(coll_ave[1:])
popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, x, y, sigma=error[1:])
grad, inter, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
```

These give me great info, just not quite what I'm looking for. As far as I'm aware, polyfit doesn't work for linear models, and I'd rather work with the loglog of my data than the raw data, as I know what gradient I'm after. If there's a numpy or scipy version, that would be great. Or a modification to curve_fit or linregress that would make it work.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: If you are asking for a method to fit data to a logarithmic curve, it is a statistical problem. If you got the method, you want to know how to implement it using Python, it is the question asked here. I am not sure if you are the former or latter.

Answer (score 0):

So I basically want numpy.corrcoef(), which takes a 2D array and finds the correlation coefficient of the two data sets.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

This gives a measure of how well my data fits the model. 1 means it's a perfect correlation, 0 means there is no correlation whatsoever, and positive and negative values tell you if the values are both growing/shrinking together, or ones growing and ones shrinking.